# Using a /23 netmask with a 192.168.x.x network

Tags: networking, subnet

My little `/24` home network is getting quite crowded due to the huge influx of IP devices. So far I have been using `192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254` with a `/24` netmask. Is it possible to just switch to `192.168.0.1 - 192.168.1.254/23`? I know that these addresses are all still part of the reserved space for private IP addresses, however, I'm unsure whether I can use a `/23` netmask.

I know I could use `172.16.0.1 - 172.31.0.0/16` but I'm not seeing the need for such a large network.

Comment: As grawity already wrote: Yes, this should just work. two points though. 1) If you have any static entries then makes sure to also change their network masks (else they have an invalid broadcast address). 2) That 172 16 range is a /12, not a /16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any netmask you want, so long as it doesn't exceed the full reserved 192.168.0.0/16 range (or 172.16.0.0/12, or 10.0.0.0/8). The address itself has no effect on this.

(The only exception is very old software from 1980's which still used classful addressing (which would consider the network a Class C one and might not allow supernets). However, such software is practically extinct by now. As long as you can specify a netmask, you should be fine.)